# Flask socketio emit through background task

Tags: python, python-multithreading, flask-socketio

I am trying to emit messages to frontend through a background task that will run on a different thread and will be triggered when socketio event is listened in backend. I have tried two approaches:

1. Using thread.start() : (Code attached)

Problem : This approach runs the chatbot_background task on a different thread but the socketio emitted messages don't reach the frontend.

2. Using socketio.start_background_task() : (Code attached)

Problem : This approach properly emits the socketio messages from chatbot_background but blocks other backend APIs while it is running.

Any suggested approach that will properly emit the messages from chatbot_background and will run chatbot_background in a different thread such that other backend APIs are not kept pending will be appreciated.

Code for approach 1:

```
def chatbot_background(socketio, docs, query, organization, user):
    try:
        response, document_name = chatbot(docs, query)
        conversation = Conversation(query=query, response=response, document_name=document_name, organization=organization, user=user)
        conversation.save()
        socketio.send("robot_message", {"response": response, "document_name": document_name, "message": ''})
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in chatbot_background:", e, flush=True)
        socketio.emit("robot_message", {"response": None, "document_name": None, "message": "An error occurred while processing your query"})
    
# socket connection with live chat for chatbot
@socketio.on("client_message")
def handle_new_message(msg):
    email = msg.get("email")
    socketio.emit("chat_start", {"message": "Response generation in progress"})
    user = User.objects(email=email).first()
    if user:
        organization_users = User.objects(organization=user.organization)
        organization_user_ids = [u.id for u in organization_users]
        user_pdfs = PdfDocuments.objects(user__in=organization_user_ids)
        pdf_ids = [pdf.id for pdf in user_pdfs]
        summaries = DocumentsSummary.objects(pdfdocuments__in=pdf_ids)
        if summaries:
            query = msg.get('message')
            docs = {summary.pdfdocuments.document_name: summary.summary for summary in summaries}
            thread = Thread(target=chatbot_background, args=(socketio, docs, query, user.organization, user))
            thread.start()
            
    else:
        socketio.emit("robot_message", {"response": None, "document_name":None,"message": "An error occurred while processing your query"})`
```

Code for approach 2:

```
def chatbot_background(socketio, docs, query, organization, user):
    try:
        response, document_name = chatbot(docs, query)
        conversation = Conversation(query=query, response=response, document_name=document_name, organization=organization, user=user)
        conversation.save()
        socketio.send("robot_message", {"response": response, "document_name": document_name, "message": ''})
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in chatbot_background:", e, flush=True)
        socketio.emit("robot_message", {"response": None, "document_name": None, "message": "An error occurred while processing your query"})
    
# socket connection with live chat for chatbot
@socketio.on("client_message")
def handle_new_message(msg):
    email = msg.get("email")
    socketio.emit("chat_start", {"message": "Response generation in progress"})
    user = User.objects(email=email).first()
    if user:
        organization_users = User.objects(organization=user.organization)
        organization_user_ids = [u.id for u in organization_users]
        user_pdfs = PdfDocuments.objects(user__in=organization_user_ids)
        pdf_ids = [pdf.id for pdf in user_pdfs]
        summaries = DocumentsSummary.objects(pdfdocuments__in=pdf_ids)
        if summaries:
            query = msg.get('message')
            docs = {summary.pdfdocuments.document_name: summary.summary for summary in summaries}
            socketio.start_background_task(target=chatbot_background, socketio=socketio, docs=docs, query=query, organization=user.organization, user=user)
            
    else:
        socketio.emit("robot_message", {"response": None, "document_name":None,"message": "An error occurred while processing your query"})
```